# magento shopping cart does not get clear

Tags: php, magento

I am developing an application in magento. I have 3 step checkout using onepage checkout. 1.Billing information 2. payment Info 3. Order review. Shipping information is merged with billing information. When I place an order shopping cart does not get clear. How to clear shopping cart after placing order successfully. but when I put this piece of code.

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item )
{
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();

}
```

shopping cart gets clear but user automatically gets redirected from order summary to cart page.

I need to empty cart in savePaymentAction() in OnpageController.php
 Can anyone please guide me. how to fix this?

Comment: Did you tried using `Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->clear();` ??

Comment: yes I did. when I put this code I cant go to order review page from payment information I think session gets empty. according to my structure I have to put this code in  "public function savePaymentAction()" in OnepageController.php

Comment: After clearing your cart, you can redirect it to wherever you want. This code will redirect user to cart page ` $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`

Comment: "foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();" if I use this code and I dont want to redirect user from order summary page then what should I do? any idea? Thnx for your time

Comment: after putting this code user gets redirected to cart page that I dont want

Comment: You mean redirect user to order view page ?

Comment: I mean Order Review page where user can see "Thank you for your purchase" and "Your order has been submitted successfully"

Answer (score 3):

Below are two solutions:

Answer 1: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();`

Answer 2: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();`

Comment: You also need to save: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()-save();

Comment: Yes Daniel, truncate is used for save the truncated object. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Clear shopping cart**

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}

//Redirect back to order view page
$this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));

//Redirect back to cart page or wherever you wish
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

If you also want to **Clear entire session**

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any of the below-mentioned codes in ovserver after place order event.

```
1. <?php Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate(); ?>    
2. <?php Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear(); ?>
3. <?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->delete(); ?>
```