# Item names disappear on checkout in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem in my Magento site wherein an item in a cart of a registered customer doesn't get cleared after checking out. Thus I searched stackoverflow and found this solution: [magento shopping cart does not get clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177094/magento-shopping-cart-does-not-get-clear)

After implement it by adding this in my one page checkout phtml file, the item names and picture disappear.

```
 foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){

     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
 }
```

Now, I can place an order without any problems. The cart now clears after checking out. However, in the reviews block, I can only see the prices, the item name, description and photo are now gone. :(

I think the problem is in this line, but I'm not sure: ->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item. Maybe my $item is different or should be replace to something to show the items.

Did I miss something or forgot to add something in the code? :(

Answer (score 0):

First of remove the code and check any third party module have you installed.

If then disabled that module and check it.

Comment: The only thing I installed is FACILE Checkout – Magento One Step Checkout http://www.cogzidel.com/one-step-checkout/. If it's disabled, everything works just fine. I think the problem is with the extension, but I just don't know how to fix it. Maybe you have an idea. :D Hehe.

Comment: Check extension layout file and compare with original file.

Comment: Nothing was changed. Everything is the same. I have reported this to the extension developer. :))